# Injecting angularjs service inside a controller gives error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to inject an Angularjs service inside an Angularjs controller but it gives me error.

**service.js**

```
angular.module('gbuyRef',[]).factory('globalDealListService'.function(){
  var globalDealList = {};

  return {
      getGlobalDealList: function () {
      return globalDealList;
      },
      setGlobalDealList: function (value) {
      globalDealList = value;
      }
  };

})
```

**Controller.js**

```
angular.module('gbuyRef').controller('HomeController',['$scope', 'globalDealListService', function ($scope,$window,$http,$cookies,globalDealListService) {

    $scope.logOut = function() {
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/logOut',
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
            // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log($cookies.globalProductList)

            $window.location.href="/static/html/login.html"
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $window.alert("error")
        });
    }
}]);
```

Could some one tell me what I am doing wrong?I am getting the below error in Firebug.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/$injector/unpr?p0=globalDealListServiceProvider%20%3C-%20globalDealListService t/<@http://localhost:8100/static/js/external/angular/angular.min.js:6 Yb/l.$injector<@http://localhost:8100/static/js/external/angular/angular.min.js:32 c@http://localhost:8100/static/js/external/angular/angular.min.js:30....
```

Comment: `['$scope', 'globalDealListService', function ($scope,$window,$http,$cookies,globalDealListService)` these lists don't match for 1

Comment: thanks @hassassin , how to match it then?

Comment: use angular.js instead of angular.min.js for more readable debug from angular. you will see the injection chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one of your parameters that's being injected need to be listed in the array. See "array notation" here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

```
 .controller('HomeController',['$scope', '$window', '$http', '$cookies', 'globalDealListService', 
    function ($scope,$window,$http,$cookies,globalDealListService) {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: still getting error.Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/$injector/unpr?p0=globalDealListServiceProvider%20%3C-%20globalDealListService t/<@http://localhost:8100/static/js/external/angular/angular.min.js:6 Yb/l.$injector<@http://localhost:8100/static/js/external/angular/angular.min.js:32 c@http://localhost:8100/static/js/external/angular/angular.min.js:30

Comment: first: is your file really there ? .. chrome -> f12 -> ctrl+o to search for your file `service.js` //
second: evaluate in console `angular.injector(['ng', 'gbuyRef']).has('globalDealListService')` and you will see if you really have registered this service on gbuyRef module